# From a single JSON create and insert multiple rows to BigQuery with Pub/Sub and Dataflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have created a Beam Dataflow pipeline that parses a single JSON from a PubSub topic:

```
{
    "data": "test data",
    "options": {
        "test options": "test",
        "test_units": {
            "test": {
                "test1": "test1",
                "test2": "test2"
            },
            "test2": {
                "test1": "test1",
                "test2": "test2"
            },
            "test3": {
                "test1": "test1",
                "test2": "test2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My output is something like this:

```
{
  "data": "test data",
  "test_test_unit": "test1",
  "test_test_unit": "test2",
  "test1_test_unit": "test1",
    ...
},
{
  "data": "test data",
  "test_test_unit": "test1",
  "test_test_unit": "test2",
  "test1_test_unit": "test1",
    ...

}
```

Basically what I'm doing is flattening the data based on how many `test_units` are in the JSON from the PubSub and returning that many rows in a single dict.

I have created a `Class` to flatten the data which returns a `dict` of rows.

Here is my Beam pipeline:

```py
lines = ( p | 'Read from PubSub' >> beam.io.ReadStringsFromPubSub(known_args.input_topic)
            | 'Parse data' >> beam.DoFn(parse_pubsub())
            | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                known_args.output_table,
                schema=table_schema,
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
            )
        )
```

Here is some of the `class` to handle the flattening:

```py
class parse_pubsub(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
    # ...
    # flattens the data
    # ...
    return rows
```

Here is the error from the Stackdriver logs:

```
Error processing instruction -138. Original traceback is Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 151, in _execute
response = task() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", 
line 186, in <lambda> self._execute(lambda: worker.do_instruction(work), work) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/
dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 265, in do_instruction request.instruction_id) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 281, in
process_bundle delayed_applications = bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id) File "/usr/local/lib/
python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 552, in process_bundle op.finish()
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 549, in 
apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish def finish(self): File "apache_beam/runners/worker/
operations.py", line 550, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish with 
self.scoped_finish_state: File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 551, in 
apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish self.dofn_runner.finish() File "apache_beam/runners/
common.py", line 758, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.finish self._invoke_bundle_method
(self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_finish_bundle) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 752, in 
apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method self._reraise_augmented(exn) File "apache_beam/
runners/common.py", line 777, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented raise_with_traceback
(new_exn) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 750, in
apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method bundle_method() File "apache_beam/runners/common.py",
line 361, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle def invoke_finish_bundle(self): File 
"apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 365, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle 
self.signature.finish_bundle_method.method_value()) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/
gcp/bigquery.py", line 630, in finish_bundle self._flush_batch() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 637, in _flush_batch table_id=self.table_id, rows=self._rows_buffer) File

# HERE: 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py", 
line 611, in insert_rows for k, v in iteritems(row): File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/future/utils/
__init__.py", line 308, in iteritems func = obj.items AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
[while running 'generatedPtransform-135']
```

I've also tried returning a list and had the same error that `'list' object has no 'items'` therefore I'm converting the list rows to a dict like this:

```
0 {
  "data": "test data",
  "test_test_unit": "test1",
  "test_test_unit": "test2",
  "test1_test_unit": "test1",
    ...
},
1 {
  "data": "test data",
  "test_test_unit": "test1",
  "test_test_unit": "test2",
  "test1_test_unit": "test1",
    ...

}
```

I'm fairly new to this so any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the `yield` keyword to [emit multiple outputs in your DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs). For example:

```
class parse_pubsub(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    # ...
    # flattens the data
    # ...
    for row in rows:
       yield row
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to change `DoFn` to `ParDo`. Thanks a lot!